# simpleXmlElement losses attributes on PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to convert some xml data to json with a code like this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($query);
$GSP = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo json_encode($GSP);
```

Problem is, during SimpleXMLElement, I lost attributes within xml files.

Here is an example from the XML;

```
<ENTOBRESULTS>
<OBRES module_name="ModName">
  <provider>ModName</provider>
  <title>...</title>
  <MODULE_RESULT>
    <U>    http://someURL.aspx    </U>
    <Title>    AnotherTitle   </Title>
    <Field name="Main">ASD</Field>
    <Field name="ProductType">type</Field>
    <Field name="buttonText">Press it</Field>
    <Field name="buttonUrl">https://anotherURL.aspx</Field>
  </MODULE_RESULT>
</OBRES>
</ENTOBRESULTS>
```

But when I log the $GSP to chrome console it shows something like this:

```
ENTOBRESULTS: Object
OBRES: Array[3]
  0: Object
    @attributes: Object
    MODULE_RESULT: Array[3]
      0: Object
        Field: Array[22]
          0: "ASD"
          1: "type"
          2: "Press it"
          3: "https://anotherURL.aspx"
```

As you can see, I'm losing 'name' attributes during **$GSP = new SimpleXMLElement($xml)** action. Is there a way to prevent this? OR how can I bypass this problem?

Comment: `{"OBRES":{"@attributes":{"module_name":"ModName"},"provider":"ModName","title":"...","MODULE_RESULT":{"U":" http:\/\/someURL.aspx ","Title":" AnotherTitle ","Field":["ASD","type","Press it","https:\/\/anotherURL.aspx"]}}}` this is what web browser outputs!!!!

Comment: Then how do you want the output??

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate over each xml node, access the attributes, and build the final object that you will eventually encode as json.

example

```
$xml = file_get_contents('xml.xml');
$GSP = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);


foreach ($GSP->OBRES->MODULE_RESULT->Field as $f){

    //var_dump($f);

    print $f->attributes() . ":" . $f . PHP_EOL;

}

Main:ASD
ProductType:type
buttonText:Press it
buttonUrl:https://anotherURL.aspx
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your reply

I am getting the same value for $f->attributes() and $f

Main:Main
ProductType:ProductType

How can I get $f value?

Comment: you shouldn't get the same value, `$f` is the node, when accessed it gives the value. update the question with your `foreach` loop so we can take a look.